# Canfulfillintentrequest for Alexa possible if country and postal code permissions are needed?

Tags: sdk, alexa-skills-kit

With Canfulfillintentrequest your Alexa skill can be called even without invoking the skill name. 
For a weather app, if the user is asking "What's the weather like today in New York?" this should work well. But if the user is asking "What's the weather like today?" the location information is missing. The skill requires country and postal code permission.
Normally, if you activate a skill in the alexa store you can give the permissions required and then the question "Ask  What's the weather like today?" can be handled properly because user country and postal code is included in the request.
But what about Canfulfillintentrequest? Can I fulfill a request without location information or do I need to say no? How does Canfulfillintentrequest handle required permissions?

> {   "request": {
>       "type": "CanFulfillIntentRequest",
>       "requestId": "...",
>       "intent": {
>       ...